# a href link not work properly at local project

Tags: anchor, asp.net-4.0

i have two href link to redirect page to new tab.

```
<a href="​http://www.sms.infisms.co.in/" target="_blank" >www.sms.infisms.co.in</a>
                    <br />
                    <a href="http://www.infisms.com" target="_blank" >www.infisms.com</a>
```

here first link redirect with this form `http://localhost:3283/BulkSMSAdminProject/%E2%80%8Bhttp://www.sms.infisms.co.in/`

what going wrong here..please help me..

Comment: You have invisible characters between `<a href="​` and `http://…` in your first link - looking at it in a hex editor, it appears to be a Byte Order Mark, probably got in there due to some copy&paste. Re-type that part completely, and it should work fine.

Comment: thanks man you save it!